# Catching WPF exceptions locally

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

We've got customers with ancient .NET SDKs (v4.0.30319) that has a known issue with the DataGrid causing '**Index was out of range**' for certain operations and inputs.
(details can be [found here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/39591) or [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807677/bug-reported-fixed-in-kb-2484832-not-fixed-in-4-0-30319-18060))

Our users cannot upgrade (controlled environment, no Admin rights) their .NET version.

**Is there any way to catch the exceptions locally?**

Best we've found so far is to catch the exception globally in our `app.xaml` via `DispatcherUnhandledException` but we'd really want to catch this particular error just for this specific module.

Is there any equivalent of `DispatcherUnhandledException` for views?
Or any way to 'hack' into the WPF pipeline to catch the error..?

Comment: Does this exception occur during the view's construction or when it's being displayed?

Comment: When it's displayed already and updated/refreshed after reordering the `DataTable` bound to the grid in a particular way

Comment: Also, it has been mentioned that this has something to do with virtualization, so disabling virtualization by setting `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` may solve this issue altogether - however, it's likely to make the view very slow for a large number of items and may not be suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to catch this special Exception without using `Dispatcher.UnhandledException` because if there is a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` it will be thrown inside the grid and with that inside of your Dispatcher. If the cause is really an UI interaction ( and you can see this in the Stack Trace ) you will not be able to catch that special one.